# Spring project only runs on Internet explorer not any other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a legacy application built in JSP and servlet the href and pdfs are not working after the update that Internet explorer will no longer work and redirected to Microsoft edge, the pdfs and href are not working.

I tried the steps below it works, But I want how to handle same with my JSP servlet code.

**Internet Explorer mode in Microsoft Edge**

1)Navigate to the website you want to view in Internet Explorer mode.

2)Click the three dots in the upper right corner of the browser window.

3)Select Reload in Internet Explorer Mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the out-of-support Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) desktop application was [permanently disabled](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/internet-explorer-11-desktop-app-retirement-faq/ba-p/2366549) on certain versions of Windows 10 on February 14, 2023 through a Microsoft Edge update. So, now you'll be redirected to Microsoft Edge.

If you wish to continue to run the application in IE, just use [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode) instead. You can either [reload in IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-local-site-list) (which you've already tried) or [configure IE mode policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-policies).

By "handle same with my JSP servlet code", I suppose you'd like to run your application in IE mode by default (not manually reload every time). In this case, you can try **configuring IE mode policies** or **adding URLs in "Internet Explorer mode pages" (Settings --> Default browser --> Internet Explorer mode pages).**

Comment: Thankyou..let me try this solution.

Comment: @PreetySethi Just to check. Have you tried this solution? How does it work for you?

Comment: Hi, Yes I tried but this is not the way I was looking, it is from application mode where I wanted to modify..